# how to redirect to my own page after visiting API website?

Tags: php

I want to send sms through my php page.

My SMS Gateway provider has given my api like
"http://sms.xyz.com/uname=abc&pass=xyz&phone=1234567890&msg=hello"
(visiting this url in browser sends an sms to the phone number)

I want my script to just visit this url (so that the sms is sent) and return to my own page (irrespective of the result) and print "Message sent"

Please suggest any way to do this.

Comment: Use cURL or `file_get_contents`

Comment: Don't, as users of your website will see the credentials. Use something like [`curl`](http://php.net/curl) instead

Comment: i dont know the use of filee_get_contents and curl is creating problem.. :(

Comment: There are [documents for `file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), you can understand the use there. And "cURL is creating problem" does not help solve the problem. You should add details to your question outlining the problems you are having with cURL and the steps you've tried to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`cURL`** to send the message and get response and **`header()`** to redirect the user.

```
<?php
function send($phone, $msg)
{
    $API_URL = "http://sms.xyz.com/";
    $UNAME = "abc";
    $PASS = "xyz";

    $query = array(
        'uname'=>$UNAME,
        'pass'=>$PASS,
        'phone'=>$phone,
        'msg'=>$msg
    );
    $url = $API_URL . "?" . http_build_query($query);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set the url to fetch
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set headers (0 = no headers in result)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // type of transfer (1 = to string)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 4000); // time to wait in miliseconds
    $content = curl_exec($ch); // Make the call
    curl_close($ch);

    echo "Response Message == ".$content;   // Response message
}

// Now hit the function
send('9220022002', 'Hello world!');

// and redirect wherever you want
header("location:http://www.google.com");
// or
header("location:/something/anything");
// or
header("location:index.php");

exit();  // always use exit after using header('Location')
```

Comment: How to call this send function?

Comment: Simply `send('9220022002', 'Hello world!');`. Or if you are using OOPs then `$this->send('9220022002', 'Hello world!')`;